# Does oracle ignore order by clause while creating unique index

Tags: oracle

Does oracle ignore order by clause while creating unique index means An index created using ASC is identical to an index created using DESC.  Oracle does not use that setting at all.  The Oracle indexes are independent of sorting order.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: someone should explain what is the difference between `create index ix on table(col asc)` and `create index ix on table(col desc)`.

Comment: What do you mean by identical? They are arranged differently internally. Does the [concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e25789/indexiot.htm#CBBFFFFG) clarify things at all? Or the notes in the [`create index` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF53994)? If not then you'll need to expand your question to show what problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical difference between an ASC or DESC index on a single column - which is why you'd usually not use this option at all when creating the index.

However, there is a big difference when the index is over two or more columns - `(col1 ASC, col2 ASC)` will result in an index ordered quite differently to `(col1 ASC, col2 DESC)`. The difference may be experienced when running queries that sort on these two columns - a query that sorts on `col1, col2` might avoid a sort operation in the presence of the first index, but probably not with the second.